# Save specific Office 365 Email Attachments to Azure Blob using Power Automate

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, power-automate

I want to Save Office 365 Email Attachments email into Azure Blob using Power Automate and it's work but the only issue is that I want to specify to store one specific file in the Azure Blob, I mean, it doesn't store any other email that I receive just a specific file.

For example: in Power Automate, when a new email arrives store in a Azure blob container and I want to do that doesn't store any other file in the blob container just a specific file.

[image]

Any help please?

Comment: Throw a filter in so you only get your desired attachment.  Right now you're processing all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating the container before creating a blob inside azure storage.

**NOTE:** Make sure you are creating the container with unique name. Below is the expression I used to create a unique name for the container and stored it in a variable.

```
int(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddHHmmss'))
```

To create a container, I'm using HTTP connector with `https://<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/<CONTAINER_NAME>?restype=container&<SAS_URL>` URI and using `PUT` method.

[image]

I have used increment variable to have a change in container name so that the next attachment would directly go in a new container.

[image]

Below is the complete flow of my logic app

[image]

To reproduce the same in your logicapp you can use the below codeview.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@int(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddHHmmss'))",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Create_blob_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": "@{triggerBody()?['attachments']},",
                            "headers": {
                                "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files",
                            "queries": {
                                "folderPath": "@{variables('containerName')}",
                                "name": "@items('For_each')?['name']",
                                "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "HTTP": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "runtimeConfiguration": {
                            "contentTransfer": {
                                "transferMode": "Chunked"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    },
                    "HTTP": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "headers": {
                                "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
                                "x-ms-date": "Tue, 20 Sep 2022 23:39:12 GMT",
                                "x-ms-meta-Name": "StorageSample",
                                "x-ms-version": "2014-02-14 "
                            },
                            "method": "PUT",
                            "uri": "https://<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/<CONTAINER_NAME>?restype=container&<SAS_URL>"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Increment_variable": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Http"
                    },
                    "Increment_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "containerName",
                            "value": 1
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "IncrementVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@triggerBody()?['attachments']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "containerName",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": "@outputs('Compose')"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_new_email_arrives_(V3)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "fetch": {
                        "method": "get",
                        "pathTemplate": {
                            "template": "/v3/Mail/OnNewEmail"
                        },
                        "queries": {
                            "folderPath": "Inbox",
                            "importance": "Any"
                        }
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "subscribe": {
                        "body": {
                            "NotificationUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
                        },
                        "method": "post",
                        "pathTemplate": {
                            "template": "/GraphMailSubscriptionPoke/$subscriptions"
                        },
                        "queries": {
                            "folderPath": "Inbox",
                            "importance": "Any"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['value']",
                "type": "ApiConnectionNotification"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUBID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUBID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUBID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUBID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```